# How can websites be tested in Android browsers on Windows?

Tags: android

Do I need to install an emulator of some sort?  Are there any online services that offer this?  I've found little guidance elsewhere on this matter.  I'm on Windows 8, just trying to figure out (locally) why my android users are experiencing issues with an MVC app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html has the emulators.

… but it may be just as cost-effective to just spring the $40 for a cheap Android tablet with WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

well, you can install an android emulator and use the browser there (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html), but it's extremely slow,

so you should, instead, try Genymotion. It's an android virtual machine and it's pretty smooth. (http://www.genymotion.com/)

another option, is the Opera mobile emulator, but that is specifically for the mobile Opera browser. (http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator)

if you want a chrome specific approach, try this (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation)

Comment: Note that while Genymotion is an awesome third-party Android emulator, it is a commercial product that is free for personal use only. So make sure that your use is not violating its license.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to download and install the [`Android SDK`](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and use the emulator to try and reproduce the problem. The SDK has emulator images for all versions of Android, and you can create devices with different screens (resolution/dpi/size), so if your site uses responsive design you can test also how it scales across different devices and whether the problem affects one specific or all Android devices.

However, it is possible that the emulator might not be good enough for reproducing and understanding the problem. The Android SDK images come with the browser that is part of the Android Open Source Project (AOSP). While this browser is technically based on WebKit, it is based on a rather old version of it. Most OEMs that have built Android devices have signed the Google Mobile Services (GMS) license ship on their devices the Google suite of apps which includes the latest version of Chrome, which is based on the most recent WebKit version. The difference in the behavior between the two browsers is rather big.

So if the problem turns out to be with Chrome instead of the AOSP Browser, you will have to buy a real device and test on it. Depending on the budget you have and whether you want a phone or a tablet, you can go with a Nexus 5 ($350 w/o contract), Nexus 7 ($230 wifi only), or a Moto G ($175 w/o contract). Of course, you could also buy Samsung Galaxy S4, HTC One X, or a Moto X, but they all will cost you more.

It might be worth also borrowing from someone a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, or equivalent low end MDPI device.